# Как правильно убрать два ноля после запятой в цене продукта в Magento?

Tags: php, magento

Интересует как грамотно убрать нули и запятую в цене формата 380,00 руб. в 380 руб. Прошу указать место куда вставлять соответствующий код. Код файла выводящего цену price.phtml

```html
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_storeId = $_product->getStoreId();
$_store = $_product->getStore();
$_id = $_product->getId();
$_weeeSeparator = '';
$_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
$_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
$_minimalPriceValue = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_minimalPriceValue));
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);
$_convertedFinalPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getFinalPrice()));
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = $this->getProductAttribute('special_price')->getStoreLabel();
?>

<?php if (!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmount = $_weeeHelper->getAmountForDisplay($_product); ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAttributes = $_weeeHelper->getProductWeeeAttributesForRenderer($_product, null, null, null, true); ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_weeeTaxAmount; ?>
    <?php if ($_weeeHelper->isTaxable()): ?>
        <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_weeeHelper->getAmountInclTaxes($_weeeTaxAttributes); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmount = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_weeeTaxAmount)); ?>
    <?php $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes)); ?>

    <div class="price-box">
    <?php $_convertedPrice = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_product->getPrice())); ?>
    <?php $_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedPrice); ?>
    <?php $_regularPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedPrice, $_simplePricesTax); ?>
    <?php $_finalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice) ?>
    <?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_convertedFinalPrice, true) ?>
    <?php $_weeeDisplayType = $_weeeHelper->getPriceDisplayType(); ?>
    <?php if ($_finalPrice >= $_price): ?>
        <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
            <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)): // including ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                    </span>
                    <span class="weee">(
                        <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                            <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        )</span>
                </span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                        : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, false) ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(0, 1))): // including ?>
                <?php $weeeAmountToDisplay = $_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes : $_weeeTaxAmount ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $weeeAmountToDisplay, true, true) ?>
                </span>

                <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // show description ?>
                    <span class="weee">(
                        <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                            <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                            : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount() : 0), true, true); ?>
                            <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        )</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price + $_weeeTaxAmount, true) ?>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
            <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
                <span class="regular-price"><?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true) ?></span><br/>
                <?php $weeeAmountToDisplay = $_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes : $_weeeTaxAmount ?>
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                       <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                        : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() ? $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount() : 0), true, true); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-weee-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price + $weeeAmountToDisplay, true, true) ?>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, true) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
     <span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                         <?php echo  $pro->getweightdishes();?>
        </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>
        <?php $_originalWeeeTaxAmount = $_weeeHelper->getOriginalAmount($_product); ?>
        <?php $_originalWeeeTaxAmount = $_store->roundPrice($_store->convertPrice($_originalWeeeTaxAmount)) ?>

        <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 0)): // including ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                </span>
    <span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                    <?php echo  $pro->getweightdishes();?>
    </span>
            </p>
   <span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                <?php echo  $pro->getweightdishes();?>
      </span>

            <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                <p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                    <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                </p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                </span>
                </p>
    <span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                    <?php echo  $pro->getweightdishes();?>
    </span>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 1)): // incl. + weee ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <p class="special-price">
            <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                      <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                        : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                </span>
                </span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Special Price:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                </span>
                <span class="weee">(
                    <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                        : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                        <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    )</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </p>
        <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 4)): // incl. + weee ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice + $_originalWeeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                </span>
    <span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                    <?php echo  $pro->getweightdishes();?>
    </span>
            </p>

            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <span class="weee">(
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <?php echo $_weeeSeparator; ?>
                    <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>: <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount() + $_weeeTaxAttribute->getTaxAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    <?php $_weeeSeparator = ' + '; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                )</span>
            <span class="price-including-tax">
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                </span>
            </span>
            </p>
        <?php elseif ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, 2)): // excl. + weee + final ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <p class="special-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <?php foreach ($_weeeTaxAttributes as $_weeeTaxAttribute): ?>
                    <span class="weee">
                        <?php echo $_weeeTaxAttribute->getName(); ?>
                        : <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_weeeTaxAttribute->getAmount(), true, true); ?>
                    </span>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <span class="price-including-tax">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                    <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                        <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax + $_weeeTaxAmountInclTaxes, false) ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
    <span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                    <?php echo  $pro->getweightdishes();?>
    </span>
            </p>
        <?php else: // excl. ?>
            <p class="old-price">
                <span class="price-label"><?php echo $this->__('Regular Price:') ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice, false) ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <?php if ($_taxHelper->displayBothPrices()): ?>
                <p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                    <span class="price-excluding-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Excl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-excluding-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="price-including-tax">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Incl. Tax:') ?></span>
                        <span class="price" id="price-including-tax-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax, false) ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="special-price">
                    <span class="price-label"><?php echo $_specialPriceStoreLabel ?></span>
                <span class="price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, false) ?>
                </span>
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; /* if ($_finalPrice == $_price): */ ?>

    <?php if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPriceValue && $_minimalPriceValue < $_convertedFinalPrice): ?>

        <?php $_minimalPriceDisplayValue = $_minimalPrice; ?>
        <?php if ($_weeeTaxAmount && $_weeeHelper->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(0, 1, 4))): ?>
            <?php $_minimalPriceDisplayValue = $_minimalPrice + $_weeeTaxAmount; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($this->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
        <?php else: ?>
            <span class="minimal-price-link">
        <?php endif ?>
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('As low as:') ?></span>
        <span class="price" id="product-minimal-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_minimalPriceDisplayValue, false) ?>
            </span>
        <?php if ($this->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()): ?>
            </a>
        <?php else: ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endif; /* if ($this->getDisplayMinimalPrice() && $_minimalPrice && $_minimalPrice < $_finalPrice): */ ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов, советую 2й и 3й варианты, второй более хардкорный и для его изменения нужен будет программист, для третьего варианта просто дуступ к админке.

1. Это можно сделать хардкорно в price.phml сделав в выводе цены round("цена") без доп. параметров.
2. Можно уставновить формат для вывода валюты в config.xml вот [тут](http://xme.im/format-magento-currency-or-number-base-on-locale) подробно описано как.
3. Но я бы советовал использовать для этого модуль с коннекта, он бесплатный [Currency Manager](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html) и достаточно популярный, около 10000 загрузок, он решит большинство проблем с форматированием цены.